# What is C# alternative to toString() [java] / __str__ [python]?

Tags: c#, tostring, repr

In Python `__str__ / __repr__` are called by default by `print` function.
In Java `public String toString()` is called by `System.out.println()`.

What is an alternative in C#?
How can I overload it? (Please provide small example.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Also `ToString()`

To override you can use

```
public override string ToString()
{
}
```

Comment: Would you please explain how exactly to overload it?

Comment: Do I need to use override if I want to override in C#?

Comment: Yes, you definitely need to put the override keywords behind the public modifier..

Comment: That's to override, not overload ;)

Answer (score 2):

Another note, you can use string.Format and it will automatically call ToString on items.

For example:

```
int age = 46;
string name = "John";

string description = string.Format("User {0} is {1} years old", name, age);
//outputs "User John is 46 years old";
```